# How can I animate a pipe by having 2 color rings pass along it, and have the rings rotate at the corners following the direction of the pipe?

Tags: animation, shader-nodes

How can I animate a pipe by having 2 color rings pass along it, and have the rings rotate at the corners following the direction of the pipe?

I have tried doing it with a *Separate XYZ* node attached to a *ColorRamp*,
but that leaves me with 1 axis to choose from. When I try the *Combine XYZ* node with 3 *ColorRamp* nodes (one for each axis) in between the two XYZ nodes, it does not work.

Check the last image, the rings should follow the pipe horizontally. How do I animate switching from the x-axis while keeping the initial movement on it?

Initial position:
[image: Initial position]

1st stage of animation:
[image: 1st stage of animation]

2nd stage of animation, the problem stage, the rings should rotate on the corner moving along the pipe:
[image: 2nd stage of animation, the problem stage, the rings should rotate on the corner moving along the pipe]

**Update:**
*Chris* had posted a solution with a curve. The reply is much appreciated, unfortunately, I am working with a mesh (of different thicknesses), not with a curve. The pipe here is simply an example to showcase the problem. But the effect *Chris* posted is the one I am seeking to apply to my mesh.

Desired effect:
[image: example animation]

Comment: I think you'll need to show us what kind of mesh. In principle, it should be possible to use the U of a UV map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unwrap your mesh with the *Follow Active Quads* option (you need to select one of the pipe face before):

[image]

Then create this chain of nodes (plug a *(Texture) Gradient Texture* into a *(Converter) ColorRamp*:

[image]

Keyframe the *X Location* (or Y) of the *Mapping* node:

[image]

Comment: It worked! I really appreciate the reply and the entire community here!